# how to delete a record from state store by checking all instances of app

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

my app has more than 1 instance and each has its state store where we store (key, value) information which will be used by app for functional processing.
our requirement is to delete a specific entry from the state store by checking all the instances of the app.
how to delete required keys from all instances state store?

we implemented a REST API using controller and service classes, but this implementation is deleting values only from one instance and not deleting from state stores present in all instances of the app.

```
code from controller 
@DeleteMapping("/clear")
  public void delete_from_store() {
    service.clearValues(@RequestParam String storeName, @RequestParam List<String> keys);
}
type here
```

code from service

```
public void clearValues(String name, List<String> keys) {
List<TimestampedKeyValueStore<String, ?>> store = storeMap.get(name);
for (String key : keys) {
store.delete(key)
}
```